# Background Color with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I seem to be having problems lining the background color of a row in Bootstrap. I would like the background to the right of the second placeholder box to be a solid color, but right now it's taking into account the additional padding, and it's not aligning properly. Currently the background color pertrudes past the main header image.

Any suggestions? You'll need to extend the width of the page in JSFiddle to see what I'm talking about.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aukme1mb/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1140x360">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bg">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/458x304">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <p>Text here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

body {
    background-color: #f0f0f1;
}
.bg {
    background-color: #cbede7;
}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you re asking here, could you be a bit more specific on the desired end result? thanks

Comment: I want the teal background to line up with the header image on the page (You'll need to extend the box so it doesn't cascade first). Right now it does not and petrudes off the edge

Comment: Adding `margin:0px;` to your `.bg` class seems to do it, not sure about your text alignment issues though.

Comment: `.container{background-color: #cbede7;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the right padding from the left column

```
<style>
.bg {
    background-color: #cbede7;
}
.no-pad-right {
    padding-right: 0
}
</style>


<div class="container">

    <div class="row bg">
        <div class="col-md-5 no-pad-right">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/458x304">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <p>Text here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit: basically you'll want to play around with the padding on the `col-md-7` and `col-md-5` divs, to get exactly what you want.

Also, there's a nice JavaScript solution called `jquery.matchHeight.js`, which will match each column with a particular class to the tallest column with that class - which will work perfectly in your situation.

"matchHeight makes the height of all selected elements exactly equal. It handles many edge cases that cause similar plugins to fail."

https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height

Comment: Very appreciated! I managed to get the desired effect after using the examples you gave.

Answer (score 0):

```
.bg {
    background-color: #cbede7;
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to remove the remove the left-padding from the `col-md-5` column.

http://jsfiddle.net/aukme1mb/9/

I also noticed that you will probably want to adjust the right padding on smaller screens.